Precision of rotation operation of vectors
I'm currently making a simple 2D physics engine and have been having trouble with accurate rotations. I have a matrix/vector library that I wrote that can rotate vectors by creating a rotation matrix. I am using SFML to render the shapes, and I notice that when I rotate the shapes, which takes in the shapes local coordinates, multiplies it with the rotation matrix and adds it to the current position of the shape (taken from the centre of it), the shape is no longer correct as in the vertices are slightly off from where they are meant to be. I have spent a while trying to fix it but I am not sure what the fault is.


I have tried switching from float to double but the problem is still present. I thought that the error from such operation is small and unnoticeable but it is very clear. Also at rotation of 0 radians it is fine, but if I rotate the shape by a few rotations and go back to 0 the inaccuracy is also visible for 0. My renderer scales the coord by a factor, if this is set to 10 the error is more clear.
Here is the code for the components most important to this issue, if more is needed I'll be glad to add more:
/*! Rotates matrix by theta radians
 */
physicsEngine::Matrix physicsEngine::rotationMat2D(double theta)
{
    double cTheta = std::cos(theta); double sTheta = std::sin(theta);
    return physicsEngine::Matrix(2, 2, { cTheta, -sTheta, sTheta, cTheta });
}


/*! Matrix multiplication operator
 */
physicsEngine::Matrix physicsEngine::Matrix::operator*(const Matrix& other) const {
    if (this->cols != other.rows) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("left matrix must have same number of columns as left matrix rows");
    }
    physicsEngine::Matrix t(this->rows, other.cols);
    int runningTot;
    for (int leftRow = 0; leftRow < this->rows; leftRow++) {
        for (int rightCol = 0; rightCol < other.cols; rightCol++) {
            runningTot = 0;
            for (int leftCol = 0; leftCol < this->cols; leftCol++) {
                runningTot += (*this)(leftRow, leftCol) * other(leftCol, rightCol);
            }
            t(leftRow, rightCol) = runningTot;
        }
    }

    return t;
}

#ifndef physicsEngine_RENDER_HPP
#define physicsEngine_RENDER_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Drawable.hpp>
#include "world.hpp"



namespace physicsEngine {
    constexpr int SCALE = 1;
    class ShapeGroup : public sf::Drawable {
        private:
        public:
            std::vector<sf::Shape*> shapes;
            ShapeGroup(std::initializer_list<sf::Shape*> shapes);
            void addShape(sf::Shape* shape);
            virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
            virtual void setPosition(sf::Vector2f position);
            virtual void setOrigin(sf::Vector2f position);
            virtual void setRotation(double angle);
    };


    class Renderer {
        public:
            World* sim;
            int width, height;
            std::vector<physicsEngine::ShapeGroup*> shapes;
            bool showInfo;
            sf::Vector2f sfPosition(const RigidBody& body) const;
            Renderer(World* sim, bool showFPS);
            void update(const double& dt);
            sf::RenderWindow window;
            sf::Text info;
            sf::Font font;
    };
}
#endif // physicsEngine_RENDER_HPP

// todo:
//      choose a good scale
//      adding/removing objects to renderer after construction

#include "physicsEngine/render.hpp"
#include "physicsEngine/world.hpp"
#include "physicsEngine/constants.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <numbers>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*! Converts position of body in physicsEngine::vector to sf::Vector2f
 *  Uses physicsEngine::SCALE as scaling factor
 */
sf::Vector2f physicsEngine::Renderer::sfPosition(const physicsEngine::RigidBody& body) const {
    Matrix pos = body.getPos();
    return sf::Vector2f(pos(0, 0) * physicsEngine::SCALE, this->height - pos(1, 0) * physicsEngine::SCALE);
}

/*! Constructor for renderer
 *
 * Takes a world, which is our virtual representation of a simulation manager
 * Convert all world dimensions to the dimensions for rendering
 * Flag showInfo for diagnostics
 */
physicsEngine::Renderer::Renderer(World* sim, bool showInfo) {
    std::srand(time(NULL));
    this->showInfo= showInfo;
    this->sim = sim;
    this->width = sim->X * physicsEngine::SCALE; this->height = sim->Y * physicsEngine::SCALE;
    this->window.create(sf::VideoMode(this->width, this->height), "Renderer", sf::Style::Default);

    // not sure about paths, this doenst work right now and its late, maybe require user to put in PATH vars, also maybe average it so its somewhat visible
    if (this->font.loadFromFile("/home/hirok/dev/physicsEngine/arial.ttf")) {
        this->info.setFont(this->font);
        this->info.setCharacterSize(20);
        this->info.setPosition(0, this->height - 20);
        this->info.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    }
    for (physicsEngine::RigidBody* body : sim->bodies) {
        if (body->getType() == physicsEngine::Rectangle) {
            this->shapes.push_back(new physicsEngine::ShapeGroup({ new sf::RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(body->getW() * physicsEngine::SCALE, body->getH() * physicsEngine::SCALE)) }));
        }
        else {
            this->shapes.push_back(new physicsEngine::ShapeGroup({ new sf::CircleShape(body->getR() * physicsEngine::SCALE) }));
        }
        this->shapes.back()->shapes.back()->setFillColor(sf::Color(std::rand() % 256, std::rand() % 256, std::rand() % 256));
        if (body->getType() == physicsEngine::Rectangle) {
            this->shapes.back()->setOrigin(sf::Vector2((float)(physicsEngine::SCALE * body->getW() / 2), (float)(physicsEngine::SCALE * body->getH() / 2)));
        }
        else {
            // ugly and not centered, fix later for aesthetics
            this->shapes.back()->addShape(new sf::CircleShape(10, 3));
            this->shapes.back()->shapes.back()->setPosition(sf::Vector2f(physicsEngine::SCALE * body->getR(), 0));
            this->shapes.back()->shapes.back()->setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
            this->shapes.back()->setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(physicsEngine::SCALE * body->getR(), physicsEngine::SCALE * body->getR()));
            
        }
    }

}

/*! Redraws the shapes on the screen with new scaled position
 *  Called every render cycle
 *  Can show time delta from processing
 */
void physicsEngine::Renderer::update(const double& dt) {
    this->window.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < this->shapes.size(); i++) {
        this->shapes[i]->setPosition(this->sfPosition(*this->sim->bodies[i]));
        this->shapes[i]->setRotation(this->sim->bodies[i]->getT() * 180 / std::numbers::pi);
        this->window.draw(*this->shapes[i]);
    }
    if (this->showInfo) {
        this->info.setString(std::to_string(1 / dt));
        this->window.draw(this->info);
    }
    // this->window.display();
}



physicsEngine::ShapeGroup::ShapeGroup(std::initializer_list<sf::Shape*> shapes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
        this->shapes.push_back(*(shapes.begin() + i)); //pointer/iterator magic
    }
}
void physicsEngine::ShapeGroup::addShape(sf::Shape* shape) {
    this->shapes.push_back(shape);
    // this->shapes.back()->setOrigin(this->shapes[0]->getOrigin());
}

void physicsEngine::ShapeGroup::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const {
    for (int i = 0; i < this->shapes.size(); i++) {
        target.draw(*this->shapes[i], states);
    }
}

void physicsEngine::ShapeGroup::setPosition(sf::Vector2f position) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this->shapes.size(); i++) {
        this->shapes[i]->setPosition(position);
    }
}

void physicsEngine::ShapeGroup::setOrigin(sf::Vector2f position) {
    this->shapes[0]->setOrigin(position);
}

void physicsEngine::ShapeGroup::setRotation(double angle) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this->shapes.size(); i++) {
        this->shapes[i]->setRotation(angle);
    }
}


edit:
void physicsEngine::RigidBody::getVerticesWorld(physicsEngine::Matrix(&res)[4]) {
    physicsEngine::Matrix rotMat = physicsEngine::rotationMat2D(this->theta);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        res[i] = (rotMat * this->vertices[i]) + this->pos;
    }
}

int main() {
    // setup
    double movementUnit = 2;
    double zoomFactor = 1.1;
    physicsEngine::World sim(1500, 1000);
    physicsEngine::Matrix coords[4];
    sim.addBody(new physicsEngine::RigidBody(100, 100, 1, 0.5, 50, 0, 0, 0));
    sim.addBody(new physicsEngine::RigidBody(500, 500, 0, 0, 400, 400, 0, 0, 0));
    sim.addBody(new physicsEngine::RigidBody(10, 10, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0));
    physicsEngine::Renderer ren(&sim, true);
    double dt = 0;

    // Initial view setup
    sf::View view = ren.window.getView();
    sf::Vector2f viewCenter = view.getCenter();

    while (ren.window.isOpen()) {
        auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        physicsEngine::Matrix pos = sim.bodies[0]->getPos();

        sf::Event event;
        while (ren.window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                ren.window.close();
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)
                    sim.bodies[0]->addPos(physicsEngine::Matrix(2, 1, { -movementUnit, 0 }));
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right)
                    sim.bodies[0]->addPos(physicsEngine::Matrix(2, 1, { movementUnit, 0 }));
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up)
                    sim.bodies[0]->addPos(physicsEngine::Matrix(2, 1, { 0, movementUnit }));
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Down)
                    sim.bodies[0]->addPos(physicsEngine::Matrix(2, 1, { 0, -movementUnit }));
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A)
                    sim.bodies[1]->addTheta(-0.125);
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::D)
                    sim.bodies[1]->addTheta(0.125);

            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseWheelScrolled) {
                if (event.mouseWheelScroll.delta > 0) {
                    // Zoom in
                    view.zoom(1.0f / zoomFactor);

                    // Adjust view center based on cursor position
                    sf::Vector2i mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(ren.window);
                    sf::Vector2f worldPos = ren.window.mapPixelToCoords(mousePos);
                    view.setCenter(worldPos);
                }
                else if (event.mouseWheelScroll.delta < 0) {
                    // Zoom out
                    view.zoom(zoomFactor);

                    // Adjust view center based on cursor position
                    sf::Vector2i mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(ren.window);
                    sf::Vector2f worldPos = ren.window.mapPixelToCoords(mousePos);
                    view.setCenter(worldPos);
                }
            }
        }

        ren.update(dt);

        // Apply the updated view
        ren.window.setView(view);

        // Draw points and lines
        sim.bodies[1]->getVerticesWorld(coords);
        sf::VertexArray lines(sf::LinesStrip, 5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            lines[i].position = sf::Vector2f(static_cast<float>(coords[i](0, 0) * physicsEngine::SCALE),
                static_cast<float>(coords[i](1, 0) * physicsEngine::SCALE));
            lines[i].color = sf::Color::Red;

            sf::CircleShape circle(2); // radius of 2
            circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
            circle.setPosition(lines[i].position);
            ren.window.draw(circle);
        }
        // Close the loop by connecting the last point to the first
        lines[4].position = sf::Vector2f(static_cast<float>(coords[0](0, 0) * physicsEngine::SCALE),
            static_cast<float>(coords[0](1, 0) * physicsEngine::SCALE));
        lines[4].color = sf::Color::Red;

        ren.window.draw(lines);
        ren.window.display();
        std::cout << sim.bodies[1]->getT() << "\n";
        auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        dt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(endTime - startTime).count();
    }

    return 0;
}

The rotation is applied only to the (local) vertices once, each iteration

note I increased the size of this shape so it's easy to see

How familiar are you with floating points calculations? Floating point calculations always have some imprecission, and repeating calculations tend to accumulate those imprecisions and you should account for them. (And that's not always easy, there a complete university courses dedicated to that topic : numerical methods)

wrt to your coding style... this-> is really not neeed. Convention is to label member variables (e.g. with postfix _ or prefix m_)

@PepijnKramer thanks for the reply, I understood your comment above but should the imprecision be this great? I am calculating the coordinates each iteration independant to the previous

There appear to be multiple problems. The rotation of the stuff drawn in red is not accurate and is different to the fill area in purple. I wouldn't expect trig errors even in float precision to show up at pixel level on a 4k screen. The errors look too large to be due to rounding errors too. You can improve accuracy in repeated applications of rotation matrices by replacing cos(x) with 1-2*sin(x/2)^2 which is a trick beloved of FFT codes (but I don't think that is your problem). What happens if you do N applications of a rotation 2pi/N ? And increase N from 2 to 8 ?

@MartinBrown I feel I may not have explained my code, but the sim only applies the rotation matrix to the local coordinates of the vertices which are not changed, so this would not accumulate a floating point error right? So maybe it is an implementation error on my end? Also the overlap error is visible when my scale is 10 (the value I multiply all coords/ dimensions by to the renderer) above is a scale of 1, where there isn't much error unless I zoom in

In your matrix multiplication runningTot is an int. Did you really mean that?

@lastchance well spotted that would explain how the thing can apparently end up a couple of pixels out in almost any direction. The errors represent multiple rounding errors in each summation of the matrix multiplication. Make runningTot a float and round to integer coordinates only at the final stage and all should be well.

@lastchance wow I can't believe I didn't catch that, thanks so much. I now realize how important writing good tests is and carefully reading over code!

My matrix multiplication uses int as the running total causing rounding error, simply changing this to double/float fixes the issue. Thank you everyone for the help.
/*! Matrix multiplication operator
 */
physicsEngine::Matrix physicsEngine::Matrix::operator*(const Matrix& other) const {
    if (this->cols != other.rows) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("left matrix must have same number of columns as left matrix rows");
    }
    physicsEngine::Matrix t(this->rows, other.cols);
    double runningTot;
    for (int leftRow = 0; leftRow < this->rows; leftRow++) {
        for (int rightCol = 0; rightCol < other.cols; rightCol++) {
            runningTot = 0;
            for (int leftCol = 0; leftCol < this->cols; leftCol++) {
                runningTot += (*this)(leftRow, leftCol) * other(leftCol, rightCol);
            }
            t(leftRow, rightCol) = runningTot;
        }
    }

    return t;
}


It is extremely unlikely that this is a floating-point precision problem, and it if really was, we would likely see a single vertex a little bit out of square, not the whole thing consistently and perfectly rotated a few degrees out of place.
We might expect a precision issue that looks like this if theta was extremely large, especially if the OS math library doesn't do infinite-pi reductions. In some cases, this could be mitigated by using a sinpi() and cospi() instead since they are easier to reduce exactly. This workaround assumes your OS provides sinpi and cospi. A better fix is to just stick to smaller values of theta. As a sanity check I might double check the calculated results of sin/cos against my calculator, but it would be quite scandalous if they did not match well.
We might also expect a precision problem if the coordinates were tiny (float: less than 2^-126; double less than 2^-1022)
You can get some issues like this due to pixel centering. Some code may incorrectly calculate things as if the pixel coordinates were the top left or bottom left corner of the pixel rather than correctly using the pixel center. However, where that occurs, the error is always a single pixel or less, and we clearly have more than that here.  It would be visible as things spinning slightly off center, and maybe a slight jump as the solid rotation crosses a quadrant boundary.
I'm assuming it is obvious to you that the circles are not centered on the vertices because they are placed with origin at top left corner, not their center.
Note that if a GPU rendering layer is involved like OpenGL or Metal, then the coordinates are always single precision on the GPU texture unit even when you try to use double and if there really was a precision issue it would still happen at the point the library converted your double precision coordinates to single precision so the GPU could consume them. (This seems very unlikely to be your problem.)
If it was me writing this, I'd start with the assumption that I'd just screwed up something myself and the problem was caused because the wireframe was simply drawn with different coordinates / rotations than the solid. That is everything is working correctly, I just am not using the same angles. However as I am not familiar with SMFL, I won't attempt to diagnose that one for you.
